# htaccess rewrite subdomain for image directory

Tags: mysql, wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

So I duplicated and installed an existing Wordpress Site on my Server and linked it to a subdomain:

```
sub.domain.com
```

After I was finished with the work I put it back on to the main Domain but the problem now is that every image on the site has the URL `sub.domain.com/wp-content/...` instead of `domain.com/wp-content/...` and doesnt get displayed.

Is it somehow possible to rewrite the URL using htaccess so the images get displayed or do I need to change every single URL on every Image via mySQL?

My htaccess approach would be like:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.domain\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

If this doesnt work, how can I do it in mySQL? Like every link in the database automated overwrite

Answer (score 0):

I would not use a rewrite for this. That is pretty messy. If your links are stored in the DB then just update it in mysql. You can do it with one easy replace command.

```
UPDATE your_table
SET your_field = REPLACE(your_field, 'http://sub.domain.com', 'http://www.domain.com')
WHERE your_field LIKE '%http://sub.domain.com%'
```

**Always back up your DB before doing any special updates like this.**